# Is it a good idea to keep Validation and Formatting as fields or entities in my scenario?

Tags: .net, validation, formatting

I like to do a syntax and symantic check on the following values:

1. Zip Code (for US)/ Postal Code (for Canada)
2. Phone Number (for US)/(for Canada)

Now would it be a good idea to keep validation and formatting as fields or should i keep them as a separate table to apply various validation and formatting rules? Please discuss with examples.Thanks

Comment: Symantic (sic)? What do you mean?

Comment: When we say symantic, it means a "logical check". This strictly refers to validation and not formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do the check and validation with a regular expression, and keep regular expressions into an hashmap :

```
Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("ZIP", "regexfor zip");
myMap.put("PHONE", "regexfor phone");
```

You can then easily get the proper regex to validate the field from the hashmap, or better you could create an Interface (validator) with a method validate, and implement the interface with  specific class that performs the validation based on the type of field, something similar to the command pattern ...

Comment: And this hashmap will be mapped to the fields in the table? Can you discuss it further at the database level as well?

Comment: What table are you referring to ?

Comment: I meant if we keep a separate table for Validation consisting of other required fields like ValidationRule, Data_Type, Min_Value, Max_Value, etc.